# Change gitolite logs default location

Tags: git, logging, gitolite

I'm using gitolite version 3.6.3 in linux Centos

I need to change the default location of gitolite logs

```
~/.gitolite/logs/gitolite-%y-%m.log
```

to a custom location like

```
/home/my_account/Desktop/gitolite-logs/gitolite-%y-%m.log
```

I've tried to achieve this by editing **.gitolite.rc** file with

```
LOG_DEST                      => '/home/my_account/Desktop/gitolite-logs/gitolite-%y-%m.log',
```

but I had no luck.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see various values forn `LOG_DEST` in [`src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4ed15ad8e5d82995b3d55cd17446fc90a3c2b7ec/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L510-L522#L510-L522).

The actual file is derived from `$ENV{GL_LOGFILE}`: see [`src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4ed15ad8e5d82995b3d55cd17446fc90a3c2b7ec/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm#L318-L323), which defaults to `~/.gitolite/logs/gitolite-%y-%m.log`, as [computed by `gen_lfn`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4ed15ad8e5d82995b3d55cd17446fc90a3c2b7ec/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm#L253-L268).

So leave `LOG_DEST` to, for instance, '`normal`', and set the environment variable `GL_LOGFILE` to the path you want (it represents a "`logdir`").

The [OP Angelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858726/angelo) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791652/change-gitolite-logs-default-location/31793919#comment51556304_31793919) having to add to the `.bashrc`:

```
export GL_LOGFILE=/home/my_account/Desktop/gitolite-logs/gitolite.log
```

And if you need to add some timestamp:

```
export GL_LOGFILE='/home/my_account/Desktop/gitolite-logs/gitolite-'$(date +%Y-%m-%d)'.log'
```

Comment: but where should I set GL_LOGFILE, in .gitolite.rc, Rc.pm or Common.pm?

Comment: @Angelo no, it is an environment variable (http://gitolite.com/gitolite/dev-notes.html#environment-variables-and-other-inputs). You should set it in the .profile or .bashrc of the account running gitolite.

Comment: I edited my .bashrc file from gitolite account setting the variable to `GL_LOGFILE="/home/my_account/Desktop/gitolite-logs/gitolite-%y-%m-%d.log"` but it didn't work

Comment: @Angelo you need to export it. Add export in your `.bashrc`: `export GL_LOGFILE="/home/my_account/Desktop/gitolite-logs"`, and then source your .bashrc: `. .bashrc`. And note that I have put a *folder* in that variable. Not a file name like `gitolite-%y-%m-%d.log`. As I mention in my answer, `GL_LOGFILE` is a "`logdir`", as "a folder in which you find the logs".

Comment: thanks for your help, I really appreciate that. By te way, according with error messages, you need to specify a file for logs, not just the directory. But placeholders (%y-%m-%d) don't work

Comment: I had to set GL_LOGFILE to `/home/my_account/Desktop/gitolite-logs/gitolite.log` But I will keep searching to append current date in the name of file

Comment: @Angelo Ok. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

`GL_LOGFILE` is an environment variable that takes a full filename; not a directory name (as far as I remember).

It doesn't get interpreted in any way -- you put whatever you want in there, after you do whatever substitutions you want.

If you want something that interprets the `%y-%m` stuff, create an rc variable called `LOG_TEMPLATE`.  The default value is `"$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/logs/gitolite-%y-%m.log"`.  You can also add a `%d` but nothing else will be interpreted.  (Like hours/minutes etc).

(...and now I look at the code I find some dead code there!  Darnit!)